# How to plot multiple orbits with more than two functions

Tags: programming

Using a program [given to me](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59813/193) (which was designed to have a particle orbiting another of infinite mass), I tried to extend it to the motion of two particles orbiting a common centre of mass. I have a few functions of multiple variables and I am unsure as to how to make sure the functions are all calling at the same rate. Here is my attempt at an extension:

```
Clear["Global`"];  
dt = 0.04;  
Gm1 = 1;  
Gm2 = 10*Gm1;  
v1i = {0, 1.2};  
v2i = {0, 1.0};  
r1i = {1, 0};  
r2i = {-1, 0};  

f1[r1_, r2_] := -Gm2*(r1 - r2)/((r1 - r2).(r1 - r2))^(3/2);  
f2[r1_, r2_] := -Gm1*(r2 - r1)/((r1 - r2).(r1 - r2))^(3/2);  
v1[{v1pre_, r1pre_, r2pre_}] := v1pre + f1[r1pre, r2pre]*dt  
v2[{v2pre_, r2pre_, r1pre_}] := v2pre + f2[r1pre, r2pre]*dt  
r1[{v1pre_, r1pre_}] := r1pre + v1[r1pre]*dt  
r2[{v2pre_, r2pre_}] := r2pre + v2[r2pre]*dt
```

Originally, there was only 1 velocity, force and position function. Now there is two of each. Essentially all I want is a function that will plot this. If there is any.

Comment: @RunnyKine - how do you make it so that the actual program shows up like that?

Comment: At the top of the input box, there are tools for editing your post. You can highlight your code and click on the curly braces button.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem

Comment: @belisarius - I sent you an email. I hope you received it.

Answer (score 3):

`dt=0.04` is too large to plot accurate orbits.

Arguments for `v1,v2,r1,r2` are adjusted.

```
Clear["Global`"];
dt = 0.0001;
Gm1 = 1;
Gm2 = 10*Gm1;
v1i = {0, 1.2};
v2i = {0, 1.0};
r1i = {1, 0};
r2i = {-1, 0};

f1[r1_, r2_] := -Gm2*(r1 - r2)/((r1 - r2).(r1 - r2))^(3/2);
f2[r1_, r2_] := -Gm1*(r2 - r1)/((r1 - r2).(r1 - r2))^(3/2);
v1[{v1pre_, r1pre_, r2pre_}] := v1pre + f1[r1pre, r2pre]*dt
v2[{v2pre_, r1pre_, r2pre_}] := v2pre + f2[r1pre, r2pre]*dt
r1[{v1pre_, r1pre_, r2pre_}] := r1pre + v1[{v1pre, r1pre, r2pre}]*dt
r2[{v2pre_, r1pre_, r2pre_}] := r2pre + v2[{v2pre, r1pre, r2pre}]*dt

ListLinePlot@
 Transpose[
  Take[#, -2] & /@ 
   NestList[{v1[Drop[#, {2}]], v2[Drop[#, {1}]], r1[Drop[#, {2}]], 
      r2[Drop[#, {1}]]} &, {v1i, v2i, r1i, r2i}, 50000], {2, 1}]
```

[image]