# How to make animate in first person perspective?

Tags: manipulate, animation

Now,ordinary animate is the obeject moing in fix the coordinate(remote perspective).

But,can we use first person perspective,fix the moving object at the center and just moving(change) the coordinate?

For example,a basketball rotation towards to the basket,can we make this animate just focus on the basketball in the gif center,and change the coordinate?

I think this is a funny question,anyone can give some advice to dynamic change coordinate?

---

Code example(from [Plotting a moving ball for projectile motion with animate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59812/plotting-a-moving-ball-for-projectile-motion-with-animate))

```
Clear["Global`"];
dt = .01;
velInit = {0, 1.2};
posInit = {1.0, 0};
f[pos_] := -pos/(pos.pos)^(3/2);
vel[{velP_, posP_}] := velP + f[posP] dt
pos[{velP_, posP_}] := posP + vel[{velP, posP}] dt

orbit = NestList[{vel@#, pos@#} &, {velInit, posInit}, 1500][[All, 2]];

Animate[ListPlot[orbit, Joined -> True, 
                Epilog -> {PointSize@.05, Purple, Point[orbit[[j]]]}], 
{j, 1, 1500, 1}]
```

As we can see,the ball is moving in the fix coordinate.Why not try to fix the ball in the center and then just change the coordinate. i knew in matlab can use 'Set' handle function to dynamic control the coordinates.Well maybe this example isn't benifit to use first-person perspective animate.Just for the question! Aha.

---

`ViewPoint/ViewVector` and related options maybe works,i'am doing.Thank you,@Kuba.
[image]

Comment: Ps.In matlab,you can use 'set' function to dynamic change the coordinate,and export the animate.

Comment: you will find  [Vitaliy Kaurov - Mastering Dynamic Visualizations with Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=317&v=642) very useful.

Comment: Take a look at `ViewPoint/ViewVector` and related options, come up with simple example and let us know where are you stuck.

Comment: This one can help too: [3538](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5478)

Comment: I assumed you have 3D case in mind, try with `PlotRange` for 2D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Module[{
  dt = .01,
  velInit = {0, 1.2},
  posInit = {1.0, 0},
  f, vel, pos, orbit
  },
 f[pos_] := -pos/(pos.pos)^(3/2);
 vel[{velP_, posP_}] := velP + f[posP] dt;
 pos[{velP_, posP_}] := posP + vel[{velP, posP}] dt;
 orbit = NestList[{vel@#, pos@#} &, {velInit, posInit}, 1500][[All, 
    2]];
 Animate[
  ListPlot[
   orbit
   , Joined -> True
   , AspectRatio -> 2/3
   , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}} + orbit[[j]]
   , Epilog -> {PointSize@.05, Purple, Point[orbit[[j]]]}
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"

   ]
  , {j, 1, 1500, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]